# Recycleview of cardview is not working.How can I fix it?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am a beginner trying to learn android developement.I try to make a recyclerview using below cardview.But when I try to run It's not working.So,how can I fix it?
The cardview code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/list_layout"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="2000dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
  <RadioButton
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:id="@+id/ratio_button"
      />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Do the work"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:id="@+id/task"
            />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/delete"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/red"
            android:text="Delete"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

Comment: Not working means? Pl provide more details of the issue you are facing.

Comment: down vote as no details provided about what not working?

Comment: Tru useCompactPadding= true in material card view. Or if not working please provide screenshot of ui so that we can help you out to rhis issue

Comment: More details please !!

Answer (score 0):

`implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'`
After that, Let's try this:

`androidx.cardview.widget.CardView`

Answer (score 0):

your question is not clear! but after trying your XML file, I believe you're missing material dependencies in your app level Gradle file

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
```

MaterialCardView is part of this library and you should include it in your app's dependencies before using it.